# untar command works in terminal but not in bash script

Tags: bash, unix, tar

I am trying to download some public dataset from the internet and untar it. I am doing it in a loop since I would like to download several .tar.gz files, put them in a folder and untar them all. The download works and the tar command works in the terminal but not in my bash script. I do not understand this inconsistent behavior.

```
#!/bin/sh

PATH="$(pwd)/data"
cd $PATH

/usr/bin/curl "https://s3.eu-central-1.wasabisys.com/aicrowd-public-datasets/myfoodrepo/round-2/val.tar.gz" --output val.tar.gz

for file in *.tar.gz
do
    /bin/tar zxf $file
done
```

Comment: are you able to echo the file inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to use *sh* in the script but you seem to have been working with *bash* in your terminal. Test if this works :

```
#!/bin/bash

directory="$(pwd)/data"
cd $directory

curl "https://s3.eu-central-1.wasabisys.com/aicrowd-public-datasets/myfoodrepo/round-2/val.tar.gz" --output val.tar.gz

for file in *.tar.gz
do
    tar zxf $file
done
```

Let me know if it helps!

#### Note :

I also removed absolute paths as they are not needed and change the name of your **PATH** local variable to directory since *PATH* is already a variable in your environment for sure.

Comment: works perfect! how did you know that bash was working in my terminal and not sh? what is the effect of this PATH, I though I was just defining a variable. Any good resources (e.g. videos/tutorials) to learn this syntax properly? Thanks!

Comment: @G.Macia I can think on this : https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ and this : https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html. These are extensive and can seem overwhelming but once you complete them you will have a thorough understanding. I knew you were using Bash because is the default command interpreter in Linux and MacOs. Glad it worked for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Using "PATH" as variable name overwrites an existing environment variable. This causes tar to not find things it needs (gzip or bzip2 etc.)